# Avoid adding "use statement" to every file (for new Library class)

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.6

I am dealing with MANY controllers, and I would like to make a new class, that will contain static methods:

`app/Library/MyParser.php`

I would like this class to be available to ALL my controllers without adding a "use statement" to the top of each controller file.

Additionally, I would also like to reference its methods without the namespace prefix:

`MyParser::filterData($data);`

Is this possible?

Comment: You can add it in your `aliases` section in the `config/app.php` file but that will add it to the root namespace so not 100% what you are asking since you still need to use `\MyParser` to use it

Comment: Indeed, but still I must add ```use App\Library\MyParser;``` to the top of every controller file.

Comment: well you would just use `\MyParser::....()` every where instead of any alias (doing what apokryfos mentioned) .. but that is about the best you will get as import/aliases are per file

Comment: @PhillipMcCubbin using an alias you can register the class in the root namespace so you **will not** need to put `use` in every file. That's kind of the whole point of making the alias

Comment: if it is this one class and it is that much of a problem you could have a method on a basecontroller that makes calls to this class for you, then the extended classes don't even need to know about this helper class at all

Comment: @apokryfos - If register the class in the root namespace (by not defining a namespace for that file), then I can simply reference the class without creating an alias: ```\MyParser::method()``` So what would be the point of the alias?

Comment: @lagbox This is a good solution, but putting classes in the root Namespace seems a little disorganized to me. I feel like it belongs in ```App\Library``` namespace. Is there no other way?

Comment: if a class is not in the current namespace defined in a file you will always need to import/alias or use its FQCN or part of the FQCN if it is down the line in that namespace ... the whole point of aliasing to the root namespace (in the config file) was so you can do `\SomeClass::...` which is now calling it by its FQCN by alias, but its as close to just using its classname as you will get ... you are trying to solve some problem that isn't a problem in reality

Comment: @lagbox - Ahha. I get it now. The alias is basically just like creating a root namespace link (or alias) to a namespaced file. Even if it is aliased, you still need to access it in the root namespace by prefixing a ```\``` in front of it. Thank you.

Comment: He can create a helper file and add it to the `composer.json` but he will need to change from `class` to pure `function`. But you have to be carefull with the name, as if it exists, it will be created with what you want... Read [this](https://dev.to/kingsconsult/how-to-create-laravel-8-helpers-function-global-function-d8n) for more info.